# Calculate peak concurrent users given list of sessions

Tags: mysql, sql, algorithm, analytics

I am trying to engineer a solution to this problem in MySQL, but I am also interested in the solution from a theoretical standpoint because I think it might make a good interview question.

Problem:

I have a (large) database of user sessions. For each user I have a session start timestamp and a session length in seconds.

I am interested in finding the peak concurrent user count over an arbitrary range of time.

What is the most efficient way to find this number?

Comment: Depends on the indexing, surely?

Comment: Cool problem.

How do you count multiple sessions in a time span by the same user? It seems to me like you can ask either how many unique sessions you had in a time span, or how many concurrent users you had at any given moment. But you can’t really ask how many concurrent users you had over a range of time. EDIT - Nevermind, I just re-read your question and I think I understand what you are looking for.

Comment: eggyal: if you want to add an index as part of your solution, go for it. Indexing has no bearing on the theoretical runtime complexity.

Comment: Dan: I'm talking about the maximum simultaneous users, but I want to be able to find this number over any range. For example, so I can generate daily reports.

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to do this is to create a table for a series of timestamps, one per minute for example. There are only 1440 minutes per day, and this is a pretty small table.

Even if you had to enter every second of the day, that's only 86400 rows per day.

Then join the timestamps table to your sessions and see which has the highest count.

```
SELECT t.timestamp, COUNT(*) AS count
FROM timestamps t
JOIN sessions s ON t.timestamp BETWEEN s.start and s.start + INTERVAL s.seconds SECOND
GROUP BY t.timestamp
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Audacious solution. It's possible that this is the most elegant way to do it in SQL.